# (C) Displaying multiple variables on the printf line, having some trouble

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am testing a program midway through, and noticed that printf is displaying some of my stored values as 0's. Particularly when I try to, using printf, display them in one command. They work fine individually, I have checked this.
Here's my code:

---

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Initialization of variables */
double int1;
double int2;
double int3;
double int4;
double int5;

/* Initialization of calculated values */
double a_mean;
double g_mean;
double h_mean;
double st_dev;
n = 5; /* Total number of integers for summation use */

int main()
{
    printf("Enter 5 integers, pressing 'Enter' after each:\n"); /* Prompts user input */

        /* Scans in entered integer values (5) */
        scanf("%d", &int1);
        scanf("%d", &int2);
        scanf("%d", &int3);
        scanf("%d", &int4);
        scanf("%d", &int5);

                    /* Calculations */

        /* Output */
        printf("The five integers entered were:\n");
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, and %d", int1, int2, int3, int4, int5);    

    return 0;
    }
```

---

### Command Prompt Input:

Enter 5 integers, pressing 'Enter' after each:
1
2
3
4
5

---

### Command Prompt Output:

The five integers entered were:
1, 0, 2, 0, and 3

---

By the way, ignore the missing /* Calculations */ section in the middle, I am just testing my current progress...
But see how I entered 1,2,3,4,5 and only some values print correctly? On individual printf lines they work. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you names these variables `int1` etc, their type is `double`! So either declare them as `int` or if you choose to use `double`:

Change

```
scanf("%d", &int1);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &int1);
```

and give them better names.

Comment: They should be integers based on preponderance of evidence :-) And those file-level variables are not of automatic storage duration, they're static storage duration, so they _are_ initialised. I'd suggest removing that entire paragraph before you start getting downvotes.

Comment: @paxdiablo Right, I didn't notice they are global variables... I'll remove that note right away:)

Comment: Ah thanks Yu Hao, that was exactly it.. just changed from double's to int's.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!